# Make a Django application pip-installable with pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, django, git, pip, python-packaging

I've got a couple Django projects that use the same 'shared application', which we will call `shared-django-app`. The shared application has it's own git repository.

Recently, instead of having to run `git clone` after setting up the project to bring in the `shared-django-app` we have been considering adding it to the requirements file so it gets installed via `pip` when we install all the other requirements.

Currently the `shared-django-app` repo has a structure like this:

```
|- .gitignore
|- __init__.py
|- models.py
|- pyproject.toml
|- README.md
|- views.py
|- # other flat files
|- static/
    |- shared-django-app
        |- # static files
|- templates/
    |- shared-django-app
        |- # template files

|- templatetags/ 
|- tests/
```

I've read that you can install directly from a git repo and that's what I think we would like to try to do.

I added this to a `pyproject.toml` and put it in the `shared-django-app` repository:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]

[project]
name = "django-shared-app"
version = "1.0.0"

[packages]
packages = [find_packages()]
```

But I'm getting an error when I run `pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<org>/shared-django-app.git@dev` :

```
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['static', 'templates', 'migrations', 'management', 'templatetags'].
```

What do I need to put in the `pyproject.toml` to make this a pip-installable package?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/